# Is there an alternative to storing PHP in a database?

Tags: php, json, database, security, eval

I am developing a small project for myself which incorporates language and grammar.

My site/app uses vocabulary stored in a database to generate random sentences based on grammar syntax e.g.

$pronoun[0]." ".$verb[0]." ".$noun[2]

There are numerous constructions using variables such as this, with results from the DB in arrays so I can use multiple different nouns, verbs etc.

I wanted to store these snippets of PHP in my database. Each record would have the English construction, a foreign language construction and other fields such as a unique ID and category.

I realise that storing code in a DB and using eval() is a bad move in terms of security. I also know that people recommend templating libraries or plugins when people are using this approach to build sites with content predicated on different templates.

Given that I'm already storing these PHP snippets as includes, and would prefer an easier way to store and retrieve them, what would the easiest and most appropriate approach be? e.g. is it more secure to store PHP snippets in a JSON file and call and parse that?

Any advice grateful appreciated.

Comment: Its just a bad idea to have code in the db. Use include files and build yourself a function that includes the correct file each time

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but I haven't got an elegant way of listing, appending, or editing the snippets using an interface. Is JSON a suitable replacement for a database, free of security issues if using variables in the feed?